# How to differentiate $\big[\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k\big]$ with respect to $n$ without summing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, binomial-coefficients

I know the answer because of the following derivation:
$$
{d\over d n}\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k\right]=
{d\over d n}(a+b)^n=(a+b)^n\log{(a+b)}
$$
The way of calculating it is to consider an integer $n$, find the sum and then assume that $n$ is a real number and take the derivative. The real question is if I don't know the closed expression for the sum,  then how to do the derivation? Assuming first that $n$ is real, the differential is a linear operator so it can pass the sum but then the term by term differentiation does not give the right answer. But I realize that considering $n$ real is not kosher since it is an upper bound of the sum.

Comment: *How* do you define $\sum_{k=0}^n$ when $n\not\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: I cannot define it if $n$ is not an integer. I don't know how to circumvent it and get the right answer as in the example.

Comment: Then, you can't define the derivative (*limit* of incremental quotient).

Comment: So, in the example above, can you please show me how to get the right-hand-side from the left-hand-side without first summing it. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. Derivatives are for things defined on a continuous space like $\Bbb R$, ${d\over dn}$ is not defined for $n\in\Bbb N$ only.

Remember the definition of a derivative is

$$\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}$$

Comment: The sum *only* makes sense when $n\in\Bbb N$, so your derivative of the sum does *not* makes sense.

Comment: The closest thing you could talk about here is the discrete derivative a la finite calculus.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know a closed expression for a sum of the form $$S(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(n)$$ how do you even *define* the derivative with respect to $n$? After all, $S(n)$ is only *defined* at integral $n$, so writing the limit definition of the derivative $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{S(n+h)-S(n)}{h}$$ makes little sense.

Comment: True, you can use the difference operator, but in general naively passing the difference operator into the sum wouldn't give the right answer. Please let me know, if I am wrong. Thanks!